# Рандом из файла или массива

Tags: c#

Мне нужно создать строку из рандомных чисел и символов ("!";"...";".") не могу понять как это реализовать. Есть идея создать текстовый файл со всеми числами и символами, но не знаю как вытаскивать оттуда рандомные символы. Также есть идея создать такой массив, но не знаю как добавить в него символы.
Идеи есть, но нет решения, может кто предложит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string Symbols = "!@<#$^...+&%"
```

Заполняете строку символами, из которых должна состоять рандомная строка

Затем с помощью рандома выбираете оттуда случайный символ

```
Random rand = new Random();
string str = "";
for(int i=0;i=Len;i++) // Len - длина рандомной строки, которую нужно получить
{
    str += Symbols[rand.Next(Symbols.Length)];
}
```

После цикла в str у вас будет готовая рандомная строчка состоящая из нужных вам символов